# Messages not received by other vehicles because of building

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using veins 4.4, OMNeT++ 5.0 and SuMO 0.25, and my project is about intersection traffic control.

I have only one obstacle (building) on my map (by open street map), and my problem is that node 1 is not receiving messages from node 2 and vice versa while in other lanes communication is done perfectly without missing messages.

I think the problem is because of this obstacle. Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem?

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer ,  i have used map without obstacle and i got warning and veins stopped and it says that i should have an obstacle.

Comment: You might have added an Obstacle Shadowing Model to your simulation. If you load this model but no obstacles, the simulation will complain

Comment: i have deleted model from config.xml and omnetpp.ini and problem solved , thanks mr.christoph

Comment: I have amended my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obstacle (which is likely representing a house next to a junction) is behaving as it should: it is obstructing radio communication. There are two ways to approach this: either this is intended, then you would need to design a system that can route data around the house in a multi-hop fashion; or this is unintended, then you would need to remove the building or its effect on radio communication.

If you do not want to have a building in your simulation, make sure that your simulation does not load the Obstacle Shadowing Model. If you load this model but no obstacles, the simulation will complain.